# How to search files that contain both keyword1 and keyword2 in XCode?

Tags: xcode

I would like to search for files that contains both keywords in XCode. How do I do that?

For example, in my XCode project, I would like to find a file or files that contains both keyword "Import SwiftUI" and keyword "UIButton".

Comment: Having "A" and "B" in the same file means nothing to Xcode because the location isn't one of its searching parameters. The Xcode search will display ALL the files containing "A" or "B"... or both.  Unfortunately, at no time will  a regex provide this kind of information. 

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

- Goto `Find`
- Select `Regular Expression`
- Search for `keyword1`|`keyword2`

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: This is "OR" condition right? I am looking for "AND", both keyword1 and keyword2

Comment: Let me check for a `regex` that works exactly as you expect.

Comment: In my view, that's the only possible result through the Xcode finder. 

Comment: Well, I sort of tried other regular expressions to get the desired behavior. None seems to work. Need to look more.